# Decomposition of the argument of Bessel function?

Tags: bessel-functions

By assuming that the Bessel function defined like as $$ J_\nu(x+y)$$
I want to de-composite it, namely: $$ J_\nu(x+y)=J_\nu(x)*J_\nu(y)$$
or another form. But I don't know how it possible. in fact, I don't want to solve it to reach to answer.  Get the final result from a reliable source is enough. I need immediate help.

Comment: You may be thinking of [DLMF equation 10.23.2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.23.E2) which is an infinite sum. $J_\nu(u+v)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty J_{v+k}(u)J_k(v). $

Comment: May be you are right. However, this equation confused me. why the infinite sum? what is its meaning?

Comment: The generating function [DLMF equation 10.12.1](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.12.E1) is the ultimate source.